# Crash with "message sent to deallocated instance" when touching UITextField

Tags: ios, memory-management, crash, uitextfield

I have an implementation of `UIViewController` with the following code for `viewDidLoad`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

        NSString *speedDial = [prefs stringForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s%i", "fav",i]];
        if ([speedDial length] > 0)
            [self getTextField:i].text = speedDial;

        [self getTextField:i].returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
        [self getTextField:i].delegate = self;
    } 
}
```

When I touch the `UITextField` on the screen the app crashes and I get as output: **"message sent to deallocated instance**". I have the same error when pressing a button on that view so I guess the error is at the `UIViewController` level.
I am using `ARC` and `UITextField` are all defined as `strong`.
I have tried looking for memory management issues but with no success.

Any idea?

Thanks,
Simon

Comment: How are you initiating your UIViewController?

Comment: I have the following code:
    - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

Comment: I mean how are you presenting the ViewController class? Are you using a navigation controller, or presenting it modally?

Comment: How is `-getTextField:` implemented?

Comment: This is how the ViewController is presented:
        FavoritesActivityViewController *favorites = [[FavoritesActivityViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FavoritesActivityViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
        [self.view addSubview:favorites.view];

Comment: Here is the implementation of getTextField:
- (UITextField *) getTextField:(int)i
{
    NSArray *speedDials = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: _speed0, _speed1, _speed2, _speed3,
                           _speed4, _speed5, _speed6, _speed7, _speed8, _speed9, nil];
    return speedDials[i];
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `[self.view addSubview:favorites.view];` you are using the favorites view but allowing its controller to fall out of scope.  The object that creates `favorites` should keep it around with a strong reference instead of making it a local variable.

Comment: I knew this answer will solve my problem before checking. And it is confirmed after checking!

Thanks